# android: implement a scrollable popup window to select a number from 0 to 100

Tags: android, popup, spinner

i want to edit a field for qualtity. SO on click of a button i want a popup to come , that has say numbers 0 to 100. And i can select any of these numbers to edit quantity. i want this window not to block the whole view.

Comment: this looks like something you could do with an alert dialog, with setview on a listview with 1 one to 100 on there. But i'd have to ask why you'd want a popup with a 100 selectable options on a mobile screen. wouldn't this task be better served with a number picker or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

A Spinner should offer a list view like a popup. You can define your items in an array. In your case 1-100 and also retrieve the value.

In your layout.xml

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In your strings.xml

```
<string-array name="number">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
        ...
</string-array>
```

In your mainactivity.java

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.number, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: thanku . Is there an option where i dont have to manually populate all the numbers. I can just give a range

Comment: You can try following this tut. http://www.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/21-android-tutorial-spinners%3Fshowall%3D1